# how to hide or disable print window cancel button using js or angular js

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using jquery print to print my page

```
var printContents = angular.element('#myModalHistExterna').html();

        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title><link href="css/histintpdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(printContents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 5000);
```

i want to hide or disable browser print cancel button using js or angular js.

Comment: Be careful about your tags, angular isn't angularJS. Otherwise, [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331771/disable-print-preview-in-chrome)

Comment: You can't remove that button.

Comment: You can not do that. you can not control browsers using `JavaScript`

Comment: is there any single change to hide that button